# How to programmatically get the LogBack configuration file path/name?

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I'm using LogBack with Slf4j.

At program startup LogBack searches the configuration file from various places and in case of finding nothing, it configures itself automatically by using BasicConfigurator.

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

At program startup I need to print out the used LogBack configuration file name.

How can I programmatically get the name/path of the loaded LogBack xml configuration file or some information if LogBack did not find any configuration file and configured itself automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would it be enough to set debug=true on logback.xml files? If not, following seems to work at least with logback 1.1.5 version but will create a direct dependency to logback:

```
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    System.out
            .println(ConfigurationWatchListUtil.getConfigurationWatchList(context).getCopyOfFileWatchList().get(0));
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for. It seems that list is empty when there is no conf file available (=self configured). Do you know in what cases there are more than 1 file in the watch list and what are those other files?

Comment: Looking at code, it would appear to happen if you include other files such as `<include file="logback-included.xml"/>`